# How to number rows with multiple condition using arrayformula on spreadsheet

Tags: jquery, if-statement, google-sheets, sequence, array-formulas

Column **Number** is the numbers of column **Integer** starts on 1 and so on, and if there is multiple number on the column Integer so will the Number make multiple number too.

> I succed using formula
> `=IF(B2="","",IF(ROW(B2)=2,1,IF(B2=B1,A1,A1+1)))`

which is i should copy for each rows.
But i want a single formula that can apply for not blank colB such as using **arrayformula** but i haven't solved it yet.
Thanks for your time :).

| Number | Integer |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 4 | 6 |
| 4 | 6 |
| 4 | 6 |
| 5 | 7 |
| 6 | 8 |
| 6 | 8 |

Comment: Your goal is not clear. We can't see any range indicators in your image. It is also unclear which data is manually entered and which you need a formula to produce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2:B, {UNIQUE(B2:B), SEQUENCE(COUNTUNIQUE(B2:B)+1)}, 2, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you soooooooooo muchhh, you really help me :))